# Deploying vue js app and getting 404 error in routes

Tags: vue.js

I am using a webpack simple but after deploying my app to an hosting server my index page works fine but other pages gives a 404 error .Please i dont know if anyone have any idea what is happening .The webpack simple only generate build js file for me and thats all, i dont get an index.htm  file in my dist folderc

Comment: You are supposed to copy the `index.html` and the `dist` folder in your project root to your root in the server. The provided `index.html` is already linked to `/dist/build.js`.

Answer (score 15):

> I am going to show you how to do it but before read [this from vue.js docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html)
>
> Step 1
>   *Run the following command*

```
npm run build
```

> Step 2
>   *Copy the dist folder and put it in a new folder*
>
> Step 3
>   *In the new folder create a new file and name it .htaccess*
>
> Step 4
>   *Inside .htaccess file insert the following code*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

> Now you application is ready to deploy!You can even run it using apache on local machine.
>
> Please again, read [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) you can find more configurations there for nginx, node.js and learn more about all server configurations.

**Additional info:** I am using laragon + apache and after the step 4, I put the new folder inside `www` directory of Laragon, and serve it with Laragon. I guess you can do the same by using xampp or wamp by putting the new folder in `docs` directory.

Comment: How do you do this in nginx?

Comment: what if i'm using firebase hosting

Answer (score 6):

That is due to the history push mode on your vue router.

If you use Apache, follow these steps, else you can read the vuejs doc https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html:

If Apache version is above 2.2, you can use Fallback ressource instead of mod_rewrite in your apache config. It works for me.

In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName YourServerName(like yourwebsite.com)
    DocumentRoot /var/www/yourAppLocation/dist
    <Directory "/var/www/yourAppLocation/dist">
        FallbackResource /index.html
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or you can use classical mod_rewrite

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName YourServerName(like yourwebsite.com)
    DocumentRoot /var/www/yourAppLocation/dist
    <Directory "/var/www/yourAppLocation/dist">
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
           RewriteEngine On
           RewriteBase /
           RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
           RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your hosting to route every 404 error to `index.html` and let vue handle the errors , which hosting are you using? if you cant set up your error pages you could remove `mode:'history'` mode from your router or use  `hash` mode instead, [here is the official docs to how to setup your host](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html), as for your `index.html` you can find it in your project root not in `dist` folder

Comment: yes thanks i keep getting this as an answer from people .but i dont know how to configure my hosting server to do that.And mind you, i am using webpack simple i am not getting any files in my dist folder except for build.js and build.js.map.

Comment: there is an index file in your project root, as [you can see it in github template page](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/tree/master/template) you need to copy the index file and dist folder to your host, btw what hosting are you using? they should provide a way to customise error pages

Comment: yes i can find an index file in the root folder . The dist folder and index file with other files like src,node modules are in my public_html folder in my hosting server. i am using whogohost as an hosting server.

Comment: hmm, it will be a long process, to make it easy just use `hash` mode in your router then build the application and re-upload it to your hosting provider. using hash mode doesn't require any hosting customization.

Comment: my routes  are in this form "webaddress.com/about" so its stil giving a 404 error but until i manually add "#/" so that it can be in this form "webaddress.com/#/about" then it works

Comment: yeah this is hash mode, it adds # to your url, are you using `<router-link>` tag for your links or `<a>` tag?